# Adding the most recent stable Docker repository path in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver

Tags: docker, ubuntu

After following steps 1 - 3 from the official [docker engine install steps for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) (updating apt packages, adding Docker’s official GPG key, and applying the command to set up the repository) I get a problem when installing the plugins for the docker engine:

```
 sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

[image]

Based on an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082945), it resolves this issue, however I do not understand this option  `lsb_release -cs` in the `add-apt-repository` command that was used.

The docker bionic repos can be viewed [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/).

Based on the repo path and name from that link, would this mean that the following command is correct to add the the most recent stable docker repository?

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/stable/binary-amd64/Release"
```

I'm not fully sure about how this command operates, and how the options are correctly given. It doesn't make sense to me why they haven't included this in the official docker engine install steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on surmise (unfortunately), and dissecting the official command to set up the repository, this will work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` stable"
```

To summarize, this will solve the docker ce installation problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` stable"
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

[image]